# Own Promisekit promises do not response properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, promise, promisekit

I wrote my own promise and want to chain it, but the result is always only the first in the chain. I think there is an understanding issue on my side how to use them, but I don't able to find it.

My Code:

```
-(PMKPromise*)tryTheFirstPromiseWorkflow:(TestCycleObject *)testCycleObject{

PMKPromise *promise = [PMKPromise new:^(PMKPromiseFulfiller fulfill, PMKPromiseRejecter reject) {
    fulfill(PMKManifold([_addModul addSomething:testCycleObject]));
}];

promise.then(^(TestCycleObject *testCycleObject){
    testCycleObject = [_addModul addSomething:testCycleObject];
    NSLog(@"Result: %i, Fulfilled: %d", testCycleObject.result, promise.fulfilled);
    return testCycleObject;

}).then(^(TestCycleObject * testCycleObject){
    testCycleObject = [_multiModul multiSomething:testCycleObject];
    NSLog(@"Result: %i, Fulfilled: %d", testCycleObject.result, promise.fulfilled);
    return testCycleObject;
}).then(^(PMKPromiseFulfiller fulfill, PMKPromiseRejecter reject){
    fulfill(testCycleObject);
});
return promise;}
```

At first I create the promise, then the chain starts, but after creating the promise it will deliver only the action passed in the promise initialization and not the chain as result.

I tried your purpose, but still run into an issue:

```
-(void)test{
  PMKPromise *test = (PMKPromise*)[self tryTheFirstPromiseWorkflow:  [[TestCycleObject alloc] initWithDefaultValues]];
  TestCycleObject *temp = (TestCycleObject*) test.value;
  NSLog(@"Test: %i", temp.result);
}
```

This is how I call the promise, but the result of it is always empty. The promise is executed after my log, but then I can't fetch the result. So how can I get the result in my method. I thought the method have to stop until the promise is running, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Promises are immutable, when you add `then` to a promise it will not modify the original promise but create a new one.

Instead, you need to `return` the `promise.then` of the blocks:

```
// note the `return here`
return promise.then(^(TestCycleObject *testCycleObject){
    testCycleObject = [_addModul addSomething:testCycleObject];
    NSLog(@"Result: %i, Fulfilled: %d", testCycleObject.result, promise.fulfilled);
    return testCycleObject;

}).
```

Comment: I Edit my original post, because I don't solve the Problem. Is there anything else I miss?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer was correct:

```
- (PMKPromise*)tryTheFirstPromiseWorkflow:(TestCycleObject *)testCycleObject{
    return [PMKPromise new:^(PMKPromiseFulfiller fulfill, PMKPromiseRejecter reject) {
        fulfill(PMKManifold([_addModul addSomething:testCycleObject]));
    }].then(^(TestCycleObject *testCycleObject){
        testCycleObject = [_addModul addSomething:testCycleObject];
        NSLog(@"Result: %i, Fulfilled: %d", testCycleObject.result, promise.fulfilled);
        return testCycleObject;
    }).then(^(TestCycleObject * testCycleObject){
        testCycleObject = [_multiModul multiSomething:testCycleObject];
        NSLog(@"Result: %i, Fulfilled: %d", testCycleObject.result, promise.fulfilled);
        return testCycleObject;
    }).then(^(PMKPromiseFulfiller fulfill, PMKPromiseRejecter reject){
        fulfill(testCycleObject);
    });
}
```

You were returning the FIRST promise. So you would only get its result. You have to return the promise from the `then` to get the last result.

Each `then` returns a new promise, this is a key understanding with promises, but it's very common that people don't realize this. Each new promise represents the asynchronous task for that `then` block in the chain.

Being able to `then` of a promise earlier in the chain is sometimes very useful.